# can i add parameters in a child function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, invoke

```
function smth(txt, a, b, c) {
  document.getElementById(txt).innerHTML = a + b + c;
 }


function whatever() {
  function smth(txt1, "hello ", "my ", "friend");
  function smth(txt2, "how ", "are ", "you");
  function smth(txt3, "i am ", "good ", "thankyou");
 }
```

> is this a thing, (it must be) and how do i get the result if my code is wrong, also sorry about the format of the question i dont know how to ask it.

```
<button type="button" onclick="whatever()">save</button>

<p id="txt1"></p>
<p id="txt2"></p>
<p id="txt3"></p>
```

Comment: Inside `whatever` if you want to call the child function you should not use the `function` keyword. Just call the name of the function like this `smth(txt1, "hello ", "my ", "friend");`, because otherwise it means you are redeclaring the same function...

Comment: From your question, I cannot say this will solve. I don't understand what you want exactly... Please try to explain better your problem and I'm sure people will help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function smth(txt, a, b, c) {
document.getElementById(txt).innerHTML = a + b + c;
}


function whatever() {
 smth("txt1", "hello ", "my ", "friend");
 smth("txt2", "how ", "are ", "you");
 smth("txt3", "i am ", "good ", "thankyou");
}
```

> i had to remove the word "function" from before the smth, and surround the "txt"s with quotations.

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the question. Answers with an explanation are generally of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot apostrophes (`" "`) on txt1, txt2, txt3:

```
function whatever() {
    function smth("txt1", "hello ", "my ", "friend");
    function smth("txt2", "how ", "are ", "you");
    function smth("txt3", "i am ", "good ", "thankyou");
}
```

Comment: you are right but also i should have removed the 'function' before the **smth**